# c++ error no matching function

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <tr1/memory> 
using namespace std;

class Animal {
  public:
    string name;
    Animal (const std::string& givenName) : name(givenName) {

    }

  };

class Dog: public Animal {
  public:
    Dog (const std::string& givenName) : Animal (givenName) {

    }
    string speak ()
      { return "Woof, woof!"; }
  };

class Cat: public Animal {
  public:
    Cat (const std::string& givenName) : Animal (givenName) {
    }
    string speak ()
      { return "Meow..."; }
  };

int main() {
    vector<Animal> animals;
    Dog * skip = new Dog("Skip");
    animals.push_back( skip );
    animals.push_back( new Cat("Snowball") );

    for( int i = 0; i< animals.size(); ++i ) {
        cout << animals[i]->name << " says: " << animals[i]->speak() << endl;
    }

}
```

these are my errors:

```
index.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
index.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Animal, std::allocator<Animal> >::push_back(Dog*&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:600: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Animal, _Alloc = std::allocator<Animal>]
index.cpp:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Animal, std::allocator<Animal> >::push_back(Cat*)’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h:600: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Animal, _Alloc = std::allocator<Animal>]
index.cpp:40: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Animal’
index.cpp:40: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Animal’
```

What I want to do:

I just want to use a dynamic data structure that will go through a list of possible Animal objects.

I am trying to learn this polymorphism concept in C++ syntax.

I am familiar with Java and PHP but significantly less so with C++.

UPDATE:

I have added the changes as mentioned by one of the answers. http://pastebin.com/9anijwzQ

But I am getting errors regarding the unique_ptr. I have included memory. So I am not sure what the issue is.

http://pastebin.com/wP6vEVn6 is the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems.

First, your vector contains `Animal` objects, and you are trying to fill it with pointers to `Animal` derived types. `Animal` and `Animal*` are not the same type, so that operation wouldn't usually compile.

Second, `Animal` has no method `speak()`. If you were to push derived types of `Animal` into the vector, you would get [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). You can avoid it by having your vector hold smart pointers to `Animal`, for example `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>`. But you still need to give `Animal` a `speak()` virtual method. For example:

```
class Animal {   
 public:
  std::string name;
  Animal (const std::string& givenName) : name(givenName) {}
  virtual std::string speak () = 0;
  virtual ~Animal() {}
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
  animals.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Dog("Skip")) );
  animals.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Cat("Snowball")) );
}
```

Where I have made `Animal::speak()` a *pure virtual method* and given `Animal` a virtual destructor.

See [when to use virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors) and [when should a virtual method be pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843277/when-should-a-virtual-method-be-pure).

Comment: I have added the changes as you mentioned. http://pastebin.com/9anijwzQ But I am getting errors regarding the unique_ptr. But I have included memory. So I am not sure what the issue is. http://pastebin.com/wP6vEVn6 is the error message.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work with your help. I would like to ask a few things to clarify. I understand the need to have std::string speak() as a virtual method. I do not understand why you made it = 0;
secondly, I am not sure what is the purpose of virtual ~Animal() {}

Comment: @kimsia I added some links that should answer your questions.

Comment: dude, you are awesome! I got some rude nonsense from some other guy in SO who jumped on me for wanting someone to write some C++ code since I am not a C++ guy at all. You are totally different from him. Props to you, my man!! Now i know that ~ means destructor and = 0 helps to allow overriding. You are way too cool, juanchopanza!!

By the way, this is what I have done with your help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13243374/80353 you are wonderful!!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your `vector` as `vector<Animal*>` if you want to push `Animal*` like `skip` to it. And you do want pointers in it in order to be able to use polymorphism. Additionally, your base class animal also needs a `speak()` method - otherwise you can't call that on an object which you at compile time only know to be an `Animal`. It should work as you expect once those changes have been made.